# How to get auto increment id for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to store the unique auto increment id together with the rest of the fields in my document in ElasticSearch.  Is there anyway in ElasticSearch to obtain them.

I found this as a potential solution: http://blogs.perl.org/users/clinton_gormley/2011/10/elasticsearchsequence---a-blazing-fast-ticket-server.html

But I just wonder is there any better way?

Comment: I am not sure it is exist in ES except the non readable one. A solution that you could implement is to get first the number of document indexed in ES and then index our new documents with the next id that you want.

Answer (score 21):

The 1.x reference document API says that you can leave off an id and it will be automatically generated. Use POST instead of put and the op_type will automatically be set to create.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#_automatic_id_generation

Comment: anything for automatic incremental id generation (int)?

Comment: @lazzy_ms no. AFAIK that is an elasticsearch anti-pattern.

Comment: Possible a little hacky way - http://blogs.perl.org/users/clinton_gormley/2011/10/elasticsearchsequence---a-blazing-fast-ticket-server.html

Answer (score 6):

Here's another way to use elasticsearch to create `iids`:

The main advantage is that the `iid` can be backed up with simple dumps where an implementation using the `_version` of elasticsearch is not able to back up the version.

It allows to request a bulk of iids to minimize the number of requests needed.

A request to get a bulk of 10 `iids` would look like this:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/sequence/sequence/1/_updatefields=iid&retry_on_conflict=5" -d '{
  "script": "ctx._source.iid += bulk_size",
  "params": {
    "bulk_size": 10
  },
  "lang": "groovy",
  "upsert": {
    "iid": 0
  }
}'
```

It needs this (optimised) mapping for the index:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/sequence/_mapping -d '{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "auto_expand_replicas": "0-all"
  },
  "mappings": {
    "sequence": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": 0
      },
      "_type": {
        "index": "no"
      },
      "dynamic": "strict",
      "properties": {
        "iid": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "no"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

A more detailed description can be found [here](http://www.lovelysystems.com/blog/es-iid-generator/):

Comment: Don't post links articles without giving a short summary with the essential details. If the link stops working, your answer will become worthless.

Answer (score 3):

As of Elasticsearch v1.1.0 there is no native support for auto-incrementing ids as far as I know. Also the [official documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#_automatic_id_generation) does not mention any feature like this.

The blogpost you mention takes a feasible approach. It has the benefit of persisting the last id that was used in Elasticsearch. Compared to e.g. storing an auto-incremented value in Redis or any other external datasource you don't have to worry about a system crash in production. Then there are no two datasources that may be out of sync.

BTW, I implemented a [node.js module](https://github.com/analog-nico/es-sequence) based on this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to exactly achieve, this might be an option - it's still in very early development stages though: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10708