# Elasticsearch: auto increment integer field across two index

Tags: elasticsearch

I need a auto increment integer field across two index.

Can Elasticsearch do it automatically like MySQL "auto increment" field in a table?

Eg. when puts some documents in two different index:

```
POST /my_index_1/blogpost/
{
  "title": "Foo Bar"
}

POST /my_index_2/blogpost/
{
  "title": "Baz quux"
}
```

On retrieve it, i want:

```
GET /my_index_*/blogpost/
{
  "uid" : 1,
  "title": "Foo Bar"
},
{
  "uid" : 2,
  "title": "Baz quux"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get auto increment id for elasticsearch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22471459/how-to-get-auto-increment-id-for-elasticsearch)

Comment: Why do you want to use auto generated `_id` field. It is also unique. @ar099968

Comment: @hkulekci I'm migrating an old project and I need to support old clients.

Comment: @ruhungry i have tried but not work for me... my uid is not incremented

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, ES does not have any auto increment feature since it is a distributed system, figuring out the correct value for the counter is non trivial. Especially since (bulk) indexing tends to be heavily concurrent. You can typically max out CPUs on all nodes if you throw enough documents at it.

So, your best option is to do this outside of ES before you send the documents to ES. Or even better, don't do this. If you need some kind of order of insertion, a better option is to simply use a timestamp. They are actually stored as a number internally. You still might get duplicates of course if two documents get indexed the same millisecond. A trick we've used to work around that is to offset documents indexed at the same time by 1 ms. to ensure we keep the insertion order.

Comment: I guess, you have 1 indexer at this situation. If you had multiple indexer, you could not keep the insertion order.

Comment: True, though practically the chance for collisions is pretty small for us and typically the documents we care about grouping together come from one server. I guess if you really cared about having a counter, you could build some kind of distributed counter using e.g. redis or a relational db. But that would almost certainly end up being a bottleneck.